# Get $1/3$ probability from a coin in minimal mean of the amount of flips

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The classic solution for the problem of getting the $1/3$ probability of some event from a coin is to flip a coin two times and do the following:
$$\begin{cases} \text{return } 1, & \text{Heads-Heads} \\ \text{flip again}, &\text{Tails-Tails} \\ \text{return } 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
The probability of returning $1$ is $1/3$ indeed.

Let $\xi$ be the amount of flips taken before a value is returned.
$$\mathbb P(\xi = a) = 2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{a-1}\frac{3}{4}$$, because first $(a-1)$ "double" flips have to be "Tails-Tails", with probability of each being $1/4$, each of them contributing $2$ coin flips, and the last "double" flip had to be not "Tails-Tails".

$$\mathbb E\xi = \sum_{a=1}^\infty P(\xi=a)=\sum_{a=1}^\infty 2a\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{a-1}\frac{3}{4} = \frac{8}{3}$$

The question is : **is it possible to solve the problem with less mean amount of flips?**

Edit: It is possible, but what is the exact minimal mean of the amount of flips?

Comment: Surely your probability is wrong, since you always need at _least_ two flips with this scheme; the mean can't be 3/2...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your expectation of $\frac83$ flips can be beat. My personal favorite is to repeatedly flip *one* coin until you get tails; then return success if the total number of flips is even (i.e., if the number of heads is odd). You can see that your probability of doing this is $\frac14$ (`HT`) $+\frac1{16}$(`HHHT`)$+\frac1{64}$(`HHHHHT`)$+\ldots=\frac13$. Then the mean number of flips is just $2$.  In fact, a variant on this procedure works for producing a binomial variable with *any* probability using just two flips on average: if the binary expansion of your probability $p$ is $p=\frac{p_1}{2^1}+\frac{p_2}{2^2}+\ldots$, then flip one coin until you get tails, and return $p_i$ where $i$ is the total number of flips.

Finally, can we prove that 2 is the minimal expected number of flips? In fact, we can. Not just for $\frac13$, but for any probability that's not a dyadic rational (i.e., not of the form $\frac a{2^n}$ for some integer $a$).

First, let me define the rules. A 'coin-flip algorithm' is a binary tree where any leaf nodes are marked either $1$ or $0$. We start at the top node of the tree; if it's not a leaf, then flip a coin. On a result of heads move our pointer to the left child of this node, and on tails move it to the right child. When we get to a leaf node, return the value on that leaf node. For instance, here's the tree corresponding to your 'two flips, then reflip' algorithm (where I've used `T` and `F` for the leaf nodes, rather than 1 and 0, to avoid confusion with my ASCII nodes):

```
      o
  +---+---+
  |       |
  o       o
+-+-+   +-+----+
|   |   |      |
T   F   F      o
           +---+---+
           |       |
           o       o
         +-+-+   +-+-+
         |   |   |   |
         T   F   F   o
                     +
                     .
                     .
```

Now, we can compute the expected number of flips corresponding to a tree: each 'flip node' (as opposed to leaf node) at level $i$ contributes $2^{-i}$ to the expectation, as it represents one flip, and the probability that you get there is $2^{-i}$. (Note that the first node is considered to be at level 0 for this computation, since you always get there.) For your tree, for instance, we get a contribution of $1$ from the node at the root of the tree; a contribution of $\frac12$ from each the two flip nodes at level 1; a contribution of $\frac1{2^2}$ from the node at level 2, a contribution of $2\cdot\frac1{2^3}$ from the two nodes at level 3, etc. We can evaluate the geometric sum(s) for this, or we can note that if $E$ is the total expectation for number of flips, then $E = 1 + 2\cdot\frac12+\frac1{2^2}E$ (since the tree underneath the tails-tails branch is isomorphic to the overall tree). In other words, $E=2+\frac E4$, or $\frac34E=2$, so $E=\frac83$.

Similarly, we can compute the probability of getting a particular result: it's the sum of $2^{-i}$ over all leaf nodes that output that result, where again $i$ is the level of the node in question. For your tree, you can see that the `T` result at level two contributes $\dfrac1{2^2}$ to the probability; the `T` result at level four contributes $\dfrac1{2^4}$; etc, and so the total probability of getting a positive result is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac1{2^{2i}}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{4^i}=\frac13$.

Now, note that this implies that any *finite* coin-flip algorithm can only generate dyadic probabilities, since in that case the probability will be a sum of a finite number of terms of the form $\frac1{2^i}$. So if we want to get an exact $\frac13$ probability, for instance, we have to allow for the possibility that our algorithm might run an arbitrarily long time.

Since our algorithm can't be terminating, then the tree must be infinite; there must be at least one 'flip node' at every level. But a flip node at a given level is *always* more expensive than a leaf node at that level, since it contributes $2^{-i}$ to the expected number of flips, while a leaf node contributes nothing. So an optimal algorithm will have as few non-leaf nodes as possible at any given level. But the algorithm I outlined above has exactly one non-leaf node at each level; since we know there has to be at least one, this shows its optimality.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected my mistake. Do you have any proof that 2 is the minimal mean number of flips?

Comment: @Jovvik I believe I can prove it; give me a minute to write up an argument...

Comment: I do not follow how the tree is smallest it can possibly be at each height. There can be 0 nodes at some height. I believe this requires proving that removing a node from a tree and adding an infinite subtree doesn't decrease the mean number of coin flips.

Comment: @Jovvik I need to describe the tree more explicitly, but there can't be zero nodes at any height; that would imply that there are no nodes below that point, and thus that the algorithm terminated.

Comment: I have mixed up leaves and nodes. I do not follow how the amount of nodes at each level is related to the mean number of coin flips. It's more clear to me regarding leaves - a leaf at level $i$ adds $i2^i$ to the mean.

Comment: @Jovvik Think of it this way: a leaf at level $i$ adds $i2^{-i}$ to the mean. But a node at level $i$ implies a contribution of at least $(i+1)2^{-i}$ from the subtree beneath it (since it guarantees at least one more flip). So leaves are always cheaper than nodes, but we always need at least one node at any given level (or our algorithm would be terminating). So optimal is to have one node and one leaf at each level of the tree.

Comment: @Jovvik I've expanded my description a little bit (and changed the means of computing the expectation from counting leaves to counting flip nodes directly, which makes the argument a bit easier). Please let me know if this makes sense to you.

Comment: This makes sense to me, counting flip nodes simplifies the explanation a lot.